# Why wit.ai bot jumps in the middle of the conversation flow?

Tags: wit.ai

I am experimenting with a flow-based conversation with wit.ai. I took the example from https://wit.ai/l5t/FlowBased_Example and noticed a strange thing. If you start the bot right from the page above and say immediately "no", the bot calls the `answer-tv` function and says "Ok. And do you watch sports online?". Checking out the stories of the bot it can be clearly seen that the `answer-tv` function is could be called only deep in the conversation, the shortest path being:

```
-> I want to take the survey!
<- Do you watch sports on TV?
-> No
<- [answer-tv]
<- Ok. And do you watch sports online?
```

How is it possible the the bot has jumped the first steps, found an arbitrary point in the conversation where the user would respond "no" and continued from there? How can one avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Picture all these stories as connected graphs. Where the entry point is any one of the stories. The vertices are user messages, bot actions and bot replies. The edges are the bookmark links and branches in a story. To understand the flow, draw a graph on sheet yourself and visualise the above conversation. You can regulate the bot behaviour by structuring the graph appropriately.

Comment: I am not sure if this makes sense. What if we have multiple branches? Which branch would it go to and why?

Comment: It goes to the branch which satisfies the condition. In case of bot side branch, it checks for the updated parameters in the context. Where as in case of user message branch, it checks for the user message matching with the message defined in the story.